# Question about subjunctives in formal text

Tags: tense, subjunctives, formal-language

I am in the process of writing my dissertation (in maths/physics), and for some reason constructions like these come naturally to me:

> We impose that the background **be** symmetric.

> We also require that a complex structure **exist** on the manifold.

Upon re-reading them, however, I am unsure whether they are actually grammatically correct at all, and if they are, whether their use is appropriate given the context (a formal piece of writing in UK/British English).

I guess the alternatives would be something along the lines of

> We impose that the background **is** symmetric.

> We also require that a complex structure **exists** on the manifold.

but my feeling is that the first pair, if grammatically correct, is more appropriate in a formal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is a correct use of the subjunctive.  It is completely optional in formal English, but if you choose you may use it.

The first has an incorrect use of the verb impose.  This verb takes as an object the rule or structure.

> We will impose a curfew on the city.

> We impose a smooth topological structure on the set.

So I suppose you could say

> We impose the rule that the background be (or is) symmetric.

But it would be easier to use "require".

> We require that the background be symmetric.

Comment: Or the use of "impose" may be specific to the genre. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22we%20impose%20that%22&hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand what you mean with regard to my first sentence. As @nschneid points out, I guess the usage of "impose" in physics/maths is slightly different from the everyday case, and I've definitely heard and seen people (within the field) use it as I did, but then again perhaps we are all making the same mistake / being sloppy!

Comment: Every speech community has its own linguistic peculiarities. It's a way for people to signal that they're part of the club!