# Why is bare infinitive used here?

Tags: infinitives, subjunctives, bare-infinitives

This is the sentence, and I am not sure why 'be' is used here:

> The industry understood how important it was historically that smoking **be** accepted as a public behavior. Early in the twentieth century, it had been critical...

I am not familiar with this specific bare infinitive usage, so could you clarify this point?

Comment: Does this help? https://jakubmarian.com/present-subjunctive-in-english/

Comment: This is a subjunctive.  Here is a similar question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296217/question-about-subjunctives-in-formal-text

Comment: It's not a bare infinitival, though like infinitivals it contains a plain form verb, in this case "be". Note that it is better to consider 'infinitive' as a clause type rather than a verb type.